# Additional method for controller (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def add
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def f(title)
    Something

  end
end
```

I want call a method f from add page

```
<%= f(Hello) %>
```

But I get an error :

```
undefined method `f'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define f as helper method:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def add
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def f(title)
    Something

  end
  helper_method :f
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write this method on the `user_helper.rb` file to access that on view.

or, You can use that code,

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def my_method
    # Lots of stuff
  end
  helper_method :my_method
end
```